# Symfony Messenger Integration with API Platform: message does not get dispatched by API Platform

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I tried to use the Symfony Messenger integration and created a very simple (synchronous) example based on https://api-platform.com/docs/core/messenger/.

The API endpoint correctly returns a `202` response code but unfortunately the message is not being dispatched by API Platform – Xdebug neither breaks at a breakpoint in `\Symfony\Component\Messenger\RoutableMessageBus::dispatch` nor in `\Symfony\Component\Messenger\TraceableMessageBus::dispatch`.

**More details:** A `dump('foo')` within the message handler does not get called and logging a log message from within the message handler also does not result in a log entry.

Any suggestions what the reason for this problem could be?

**Note:** Symfony Messenger seems to be working fine in general in my project – I can successfully dispatch a message e.g. in a Controller Action.

I use Symfony 4.4.11 and API Platform 2.5.6 with PHP 7.2.

**This is the message handler:**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App\Api\MessageHandler;

use App\Entity\RPC\MarkNotificationAsRead;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Handler\MessageHandlerInterface;

class MarkNotificationAsReadMessageHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function __invoke(MarkNotificationAsRead $markNotificationAsRead)
    {
        dump($markNotificationAsRead);
        $this->logger->info('Lorem ipsum!');
    }
}
```

**This is the code of the class that represents the API resource:**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App\Entity\RPC;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     messenger=true,
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "post"={"status"=202}
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={},
 *     output=false
 * )
 */
final class MarkNotificationAsRead
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    public $foo;
}
```

Note: This class is currently placed in the `Entity` namespace but I did not add any Doctrine configuration for it.

Comment: Can you show @ApiResource annotation and handler code?

Comment: @shvv Thank you for your answer. I updated my post. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: General question: I would like to create RPC-like API endpoints. Does using Messenger with API Platform make sense for that?

Comment: Entity and handler looks good. About RCP - API Platform is HTTP REST library.

Comment: @shvv On https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extending/ it says under "Messenger Handlers": "create 100% custom, RPC, async, service-oriented endpoints (should be used in place of custom controllers because the messenger integration is compatible with both REST and GraphQL, while custom controllers only work with REST)"

Comment: I think this is about exchange data with queue.

Comment: The error message says you are sending an unparsable JSON. What are you sending exactly? Provide the exact input.

Comment: @yivi I don't know what I changed in the meantime but the "unparsable JSON" problem is gone. I updated/simplified my post/question. The main problem reimains: API Platform does not dispatch the message. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved my problem: I had to enable Messenger for API platform. Using `bin/console debug:config api_platform` I realized that it is disabled by default:

```
# config.yml
api_platform:
    messenger:
        enabled: true
```